# problem with pokerstars installation using wine

Tags: software-installation, wine

I'm trying to install pokerstars with the wine. I started the installation but when it starts the connections stops and closes. Then I tried to install it again but it gives a error because the program is already running.

what should I do?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, but I am not familiar with wine as well as I don't know your program Pokerstars, but I use PokerTH from the Ubuntu Software Center. If you can't get yours running, maybe you want to try this free alternative. It has an AI (offline games against up to 9 players), network multiplayer mode and internet gaming (poker-heroes.com - restricted usage without registration possible with guest account). Have fun!

Answer (score 0):

Try installing it on the command line. In a Terminal, type `wine /path/to/installer.exe` and  report any errors in the terminal output.